# Buttons in the profile page have underlined links

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Most of the button-like elements have white text displayed on a coloured background (blue on Main; dark grey on Meta):

[image]

But there are some buttons on the profile that have an underline in the button. I think that underline looks out-of-place and should be removed:

[image]

Comment: Interesting; the same underlined-button links appear on SFF (which just got the new CSS). More noticeable on Code Review because it’s right next to buttons that look incredibly similar (but now I look again, are a slightly different shade of blue).

Comment: Seems like this is a bug on whole network, not only CR. We will investigate and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch. We've pushed a fix that should resolve the issue of underlines on the buttons on the profile tooltips.